# Ошибка при сравнении возведения в степень OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал программу, которая проверяет числа воздведенные в степень, но столкнулся с проблемой

```
import math

def compare_powers(n1,n2):
    x1, x2 = n1[0], n1[1]
    y1, y2 = n2[0], n2[1]

    if math.pow(x1,x2) == math.pow(y1,y2):
        return 0
    elif math.pow(x1,x2) > math.pow(y1,y2):
        return -1
    else:
        return 1

compare_powers([412222404,855201893], [205914948,950778202])
```

Я получаю такую ошибку:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

А на `codewars` не работает, пишет `Execution Timed Out`, хотя это значения, которые в аргументах функции с их сайта

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050907/python-overflowerror-math-range-error

Comment: @splash58, я смотрел там, но не понял как это у меня примерить можно

Comment: это отдельный вопрос. причина ясна. а чтобы обойти, попробуйте decimal. но я про него сказать ничего не могу - https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/decimal.html

Comment: 1 - используйте оператор ** вместо math.pow, тогда будет использоваться целочисленное возведение в степень с длинной арифметикой, а не через float. 2 - возводите в степень один раз, потом просто сравнивайте (у вас сейчас в условиях каждый раз заново возведение в степень происходит). Но вероятно все равно по времени не пройдет. Но через decimal скорее всего будет еще медленнее.

Comment: Ну явно делать это в лоб - не самая лучшая идея. В этих двух числах почти по 8 миллиардов цифр. Кстати, отсюда, как вариант, сначала оценить количество цифр в результате и сравнить их.

Comment: Можно еще пробовать к общему основанию степени привести, тогда сравнение сведется к сравнению показателей степени (без непосредственного возведения в степень).

Comment: @insolor Ну, по сути, я это и предложил. Ведь количество цифр - это и есть показатель степени с общим основанием в выбранной системе счисления.

Comment: @GrAnd, по сути да, но приведение оснований к НОК оснований по идее должно дать точный результат. Но не уверен на 100%, нужно гуглить, школьную математику вспоминать, сейчас пока некогда) Может получиться, что и не особо важно, какое конкретно общее основание выбрать, хоть 2, хоть e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тупое сравнение по количеству цифр, требуемое для записи результата в двоичной системе счисления.

```
from math import log2
def compare_powers(n1,n2):
    a = n1[1]*log2(n1[0])
    b = n2[1]*log2(n2[0])
    if   a > b: return -1
    elif a < b: return  1
    else:       return  0
```

В случае равенства, по хорошему, надо сравнивать уже значения.

Но в случае Codewars (если это [эта задача](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55b2549a781b5336c0000103/train/python)) - проходит и так. :)

Comment: Да это не про кол-во цифр, это вы просто взяли логарифм от обоих значений. Это точное сравнение (ну, с той точностью, с какой вообще вычисляются логарифмы) и отличное решение! :)  Причём, логарим, мне кажется, можно брать по абсолютно любому основанию, а не только 2, это вообще не важно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну, вообще-то, это именно количество цифр в записи числа в двоичном виде (если взять от результата `int() + 1`. И чем меньше основание - тем меньше вероятность, что длины этих чисел совпадут. Хотя если не проводить округление, то да...

Comment: Да, что кол-во цифр вы правы, но по сути то вы сделали именно что точное сравнение в итоге ))